# R:'expr' did not evaluate to an object of length 'n'

Tags: r

the question is that Generate a sample of 1,000 independent observations from a gamma distribution with scale θ = 2 and shape k = 3, using the rgamma() function.
Create a sample density histogram and overlay the true gamma density function. Use the default settingsin the hist() function for estimating the bin width (essentially the default is Sturge’s Rule).
my code is

```r
n = 1000
x = rgamma(n,shape = 3,scale = 2)
hist(x,freq = FALSE,col = 'blue')
curve(density(x),col = 'red')
```

[hist looks like][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ep3bS.png

**but my curve can not show on the hist. its said 'expr' did not evaluate to an object of length 'n'
so what i am doing wrong**

Comment: On your code, `n` is undefined.

Comment: `curve()` wants a function, but `density(x)` returns a list of x and y values.  @Isaiah's answer works because it doesn't try to plot `density(x)`: the question asked for the "true gamma density", which needs the `dgamma()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = rgamma(n = 1000, shape = 3, scale = 2)
hist(x, freq = FALSE, col = 'blue', ylim = c(0, 0.15))
curve(dgamma(x, shape = 3, scale = 2), add = T, col = 'red')
```